# How to Query According to Different Time Zones?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to show the data I have stored in Firebase Realtime Database by filtering according to the date of the users. My data in the database always works according to GMT+3 timezone. But if my user's time is different from GMT+3, the query will not work correctly. I need some information and code for this. Does anyone have any idea how I can do it?

I store my data as unixtime in the database.
For example: 1621717200

```
startData = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("totals")
                .child(moTracks);
        PeriodHow = startData.orderByChild("availableDate").startAt(1621717200).endAt(1621803599);
        PeriodHow.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
}
}
```

Regards.

Comment: Since you need a conversion anyway, consider to store times in UTC (GMT+0) for a time zone neutral representation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```java
LocalDate
.of( 2021 , Month.SEPTEMBER , 26 )
.atStartOfDay( 
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )
)
.toInstant()
.getEpochSecond()
```

To complete your query, do the same but add a day by calling `LocalDate#plusDays( 1 )` for the first moment of the next day.

## Details

I do not know Firebase. But I can show you how to get a count of seconds since [epoch reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)).

Of the [couple dozen commonly used epoch references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing), I assume your Firebase tooling is using the first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

Get the current moment as a count of whole seconds since 1970-01-01T00:00Z. We use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) to represent a moment as seen in UTC.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = Instant.now().getEpochSecond() ;
```

Apparently you want to represent an entire day using counts of whole seconds since epoch, but track the day as seen in a particular time zone. Be aware that for any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. It can be “tomorrow” in Tokyo Japan while still “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
```

You may choose to use the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

And furthermore, politicians frequently alter the rules of a time zone, creating anomalies such as days that run longer or shorter than 24 hours, and days that do not start at 00:00. So we let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day by calling `LocalDate#atStartOfDay`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , Month.SEPTEMBER , 26 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Adjust that moment from the specific time zone to UTC by extracting a `Instant` object from our `ZonedDateTime` object. We have the same moment, the same point on the timeline, but we perceive a different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instantStart = zdtStart.toInstant() ;
```

From the `Instant` we get a count of whole seconds since the epoch reference. Beware of data loss: any fractional second on the `Instant` is ignored, of course.

```
long start = instantStart.getEpochSecond() ;
```

For the beginning of the day, we use the Half-Open approach where the beginning of the day is *inclusive* while the ending *exclusive*. So a day starts with the first moment of the day and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the next day. This avoids the problem of determining the infinitely divisible last moment.

```
LocalDate nextDay = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtEnd = nextDay.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Calculate time elapsed, the length of a day on that date in that zone.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( zdtStart , zdtEnd ) ;  // 23 hours, not 24, for Daylight Saving Time (DST) cut-over on that date in that zone.
```

Adjust to UTC (an offset of zero). Extract a count of whole seconds since epoch reference.

```
Instant instantEnd = zdtEnd.toInstant() ;
long end = instantEnd.getEpochSecond() ;
```

Now you can perform your query using `start` and `end`. Be sure your query is framed as Half-Open. Do *not* use the SQL command `BETWEEN`. Criteria should be using logic of “not before the start AND before the end”.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM some_table_
WHERE when_ !< ?
AND when_ < ?
;
```

… while using `start` and `end` longs as the values to plug into those placeholders.

By the way, if your database offers date-time data types, your should be using those as the type of your table columns rather than using mere integers.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: First of all, thank you for this wonderful, revealing answer. But when I run the code, I can't get a log output

Comment: @MehmetAslan That code of off the top of my head, untested. May need fixing. If you can’t fix it now, I’ll do so later when I’m at a computer.

Comment: I have not been able to run the code. I would appreciate it if you fix it, regards

Comment: @MehmetAslan The code runs successfully without any changes. See [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/dExb8p). You can fork that page and put in your own time zone.

Comment: My fault. Well ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ("Pacific / Auckland") What is the way to automatically get this information from the user?

Comment: @MehmetAslan You either ask the user, usually through a dialog box letting them choose from lists, or you use `ZoneId.systemDefault` to get the JVM’s current default time zone.